# Populating a page with array data

Tags: php, forms

I'll try and be brief but concise.

I have a PHP form page that populates a drop-down box with data (magazine names) from an array, and then, if posted, outputs it to another page.

However, I have a second array within the form (containing subscription links), that I also need to send to the output page, depending on what was chosen from the drop-down box. If that makes sense.

For example, if the value for for `$arrayOne[7]` is chosen from the drop-down box, I need to post_GET the value for `$arrayTwo[7]` over to the output page automatically, as well.

Can anyone help?

**default.php**:

```
$arrayOne[0] = "magazineA";
$arrayOne[1] = "magazineB";
etc...

$arrayTwo[0] = "subscriptionLinkA";
$arrayTwo[1] = "subscriptionLinkB";
etc...

<form action="index2.php" method="get">
<?php

echo '<select name="publication">';
foreach ($magazine as $publication)
{
    echo '<option name="publication" value="' . $publication . '">' . $publication . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**index2.php**:

```
<p>
If you have subscribed to <?php echo $_GET["publication"]; ?>,
you will receive your hard-copy in due course. If you are not a current subscriber,
<a href="#">click here</a> to subscribe.
</p>
```

Comment: Add your trying PHP, then we add the suggestions or solutions.

Comment: What do you see if you `print_r($_GET)` in index2.php ?

Comment: Sorry, that was quick and bad thoughts.

Comment: `Array ( [publication] => magazineA )`

Comment: You can use for loop instead of foreach to utilize subscript counting. And use that count for the $arrayOne[7] $arrayTwo[7] to be passed inside hidden inputs.

Comment: You'll also need to utilize JS to get the current selected option's value to be set for the hidden two inputs before submitting.

Comment: Can I politely ask for some code? Procedural coding really isn't my forté!

Comment: var magazine=$("#publication option:selected").text();

Comment: the above jQuery will hold the value from the select box. And then you can set the hidden value. You would have to create a JS array with the PHP array values to fill in the hidden values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value from `$array2` is completely dependant on the value of `$array1`, `$_GET['a1']` can act as a lookup for the other value.  ie you don't have to pass `$a2` at all.

On index2.php, you'd have something like this:

```
$arr2= array( 'magazineA' => 'subscriptionLinkA',
              'magazineB' => 'subscriptionLinkB');

$pub= $_GET['a1']; //you'd want to sanitize this value of course
$link= $arr2[$pub];

echo  <<< EOT
<p>
If you have subscribed to $pub
you will receive your hard-copy in due course. If you are not a current subscriber,
<a href="$link">click here</a> to subscribe.
</p>
EOT;
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your help. Moving the second array to the second page was so much simpler in the end, and I've implemented this solution and it works perfectly. - I completely forgot all about associative arrays, thinking the only way I could write one was with a numerical key.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

You can use Javascript to fill a hidden input field (`<input type="hidden"...`) with the selected option of the `<select>` field, at the moment the dropdown selection in your `<select>` field is changed.

Some code for **default.php**:

```
<form action="index2.php" method="get">
<?php

echo '<select id="pubfield" name="publication">';
foreach ($magazine as $publication) {
    echo '<option name="publication" value="'.$publication.'">'.$publication.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND!">
    <input type="hidden" id="hid" name="arr2" value="" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Using jQuery, include the js file with jQuery.
        $('select#pubfield').change(function() {
            var value = $("select#pubfield option:selected").text(); // Get the selected option from the select field.
            $('input#hid').value(value);
        });
        $('select#pubfield').change();

    </script>
</form>
```

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MCEmperor/z8Gp3/11/).

**Notice**: since Javascript is client-side, I suggest you to do not trust the value sent by the HTML form. Always perform a server-side check on it.

## Update:

### Method 2

You can also set the index value as `<option value="">` and send them with the form.

```
$magazines = array(
    "magazineA", // will be index 0
    "magazineB", // will be index 1
    ...
);
...
foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($magazines); $i++) {
    echo '<option value="'.$i. '">'.$magazines[$i].'</option>';
    // The 'value' attribute of the selected option will be posted.
}
...
```

Then you don't even need the hidden input field, but the index is passed to the `$_POST` variable.
For example, if 'magazineB' is selected, value `1` will be passed to `$_POST['publication']`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I always have the hidden variable as the selected value in arrayOne, how do I relate that to the relevant arrayTwo value?

Comment: You can check for equality. Iterate over the values in `arrayTwo`, return the index if the value of the `$_GET['hid']` equals the current element in `arrayTwo`.

Comment: You can also send the index value as the value of the selected option.